# Show that $f$ is continuous if $p=1$ and constant if $p>1$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that for some $M>0$ and all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$, a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ satisfies $$|f(x)-f(y)|\leq M(x-y)^p$$
Show that $f$ is continuous if $p=1$ and constant if $p>1$.

I don't know whether do approach this question using the definition of continuity or some tricks surrounding it. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If $p=1$ it's actually Lipschitz, which is a stronger condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $p > 1$. Note that $|f(x) - f(y)| < M(x-y)^p$, and write $\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|} < M(x-y)^{p-1}$. Take the limit of both sides as $y \to x$ to see that since the right hand side converges to $0$, the left hand side also does. Therefore, $f$ has derivative zero at every point, and hence is constant. This condition is actually called $(M,p)$-Holder continuity.

In general, this result would hold : any $(M,\alpha)$-Holder continuous function on an interval is constant if $\alpha > 1$, for the same reason as above.

If $p=1$, then it merely means that $|f(x)-f(y)| < M|x-y|$ for all $x,y$. Therefore, given $\epsilon > 0$, simply take $\delta = \frac \epsilon M$ in the definition of continuity, to get that infact $f$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb R$. Actually, the above condition is called Lipschitz continuity.

Answer (score 1):

For $p>1$, and $x\ne y$, write $\dfrac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|}\leq M|x-y|^{p-1}$, take $x\rightarrow y$...